# ALAsset thumbnail have black background

Tags: objective-c, alassetslibrary, alasset

I have written my own image picker classes through using `ALAssetsLibrary` classes.

Almost everything is fine, **but there are some image thumbnails which have black background, while the actual image is transparent/alpha channel.**

How to fix this issue?

Here is my enumeration block in which I've load the image from ALAsset thumbnail property:

```
[reversedItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[_assets objectAtIndex:allItems - idx] thumbnail]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            GridView *gridView = (GridView *)obj;
            gridView.imageView.image = image;
        });
    });

}];
```

Comment: have the same issue, but try to start app on ios device, on device you should not see black background, seems like it appears only in simulator

Comment: actually I see that background on device.

Comment: Go look into simulator file system and find thumbnails, see which format are they saved in. As far as I remember, it's jpeg or some other format that does not support alpha channel. I know for a fact that thumbnail in albums list is tiff and has no alpha channel.

Comment: First I dont test on simulator; Second even if I test on simulator where to find those thumbnails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround if you use the fullScreenImage property, it should be slower for execution but it should work fine.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
        ALAsset *asset = [_assets objectAtIndex:allItems - idx];
        UIImage *smallImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];
        UIImage *image;

        CGSize size = [smallImage size];
        CGRect box = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextFillRect(context, box);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        CGContextDrawImage(context, box, [[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]);

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            TTGridView *gridView = (TTGridView *)obj;
            gridView.imageView.image = image;
        });
    });
```